# A Typescript syntax clarification

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I am reading a code written in Typescript. I'm not sure if I understand it correctly:

```
export class MyClass<B> {
  value: B;

  constructor(value: B) {
    this.value = value;
  }

  isMyClass(): this is MyClass<B> {
    return true;
  }
}
```

1. What does the `<B>` stand for? What does it represent, a Type? If so, what Type is it?
2. What is `this is MyClass<B>` in `isMyClass(): this is MyClass<B>`? Is it being evaluated for true or false? Why not to put this inside of the function itself then, something like this:

```
  isMyClass() {
    if (this is MyClass) {
      return true;
    }
    else {
      return false;
    }    
  }
```

And I am not able to find the answer to a these questions.

Comment: Does B have an interface or type definition?

Comment: No, there is definition for `B`.

Comment: You can replace the `B` with any letter or letters. And it still works.

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html#generic-classes seems to have the answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What does the `<B>` stand for? What does it represent, a Type? If so, what Type is it?

That's a type parameter, also known as generics. See the [TS handbook](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html).

> In languages like C# and Java, one of the main tools in the toolbox for creating reusable components is generics, that is, being able to create a component that can work over a variety of types rather than a single one. This allows users to consume these components and use their own types.

Whenever one calls a function or creates an instance, if the function or class is *generic*, you can "pass" a type parameter to it, similar to how arguments can be passed to a function or constructor. (The difference is that the type parameter, being a *type*, doesn't exist in the emitted JS - it's just there to help TS type-check).

> If so, what Type is it?

It's whatever type the constructor parameter is called with.

```
const m = new MyClass(3);
```

will result in

```
constructor(value: B)
```

where `value` is `3`, telling TypeScript that the resulting instance is a `MyClass<number>` - in other words, that its `value` property holds a `number`, a `B`.

> What is `this is MyClass<B>` in `isMyClass(): this is MyClass<B>`? Is it being evaluated for true or false? Why not to put this inside of the function itself then, something like this:

The

```
isMyClass(): this is MyClass<B> {
```

is a [type guard](https://basarat.gitbook.io/typescript/type-system/typeguard). If the method returns `true`, it tells TypeScript that the instance is of type `MyClass<B>`.

While you could do something like:

```
  isMyClass() {
    if (this instanceof MyClass) {
      return true;
    }
    else {
      return false;
    }    
  }
```

That wouldn't allow TypeScript to understand that the type has been narrowed when `isMyClass` is called; it'll just return a boolean. In contrast, using the `is` will both return a Boolean *and* give TypeScript type information about what was called.